# Map algebra raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, error-000539, change-detection

I am attempting a GIS tutorial on land change analysis between two rasters. I have set the extent and raster analysis to what I have been given and used the expression below. However, it is not working. Could someone provide some clues as to what I have be doing wrong? I have followed all instructions... I can't see what the error no is.

```
Con("%lc1991%" == "%lc2001%",0,1)
```

000539 is the error I get and I had a look and it said cannot concatenate a string and integer. This is the expression I was told to use. Does anyone know how to construct a better expression?

Comment: Welcome to GISSE.  Please take the [tour] to learn how the site works and the best ways to get quality answers.  Please edit your question and add the information from your comment about the error message.

Comment: Please run a spellcheck over your question body.

Comment: The use of the percent sign shows that the statement is looking for *variables* in your model called lc1991 and lc2001, you've probably missed that somewhere along the way in the tutorial. When you find out what the values are supposed to be you can substitute the values or create variables http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000003v000000 with the correct name and specify the rasters there.